# EF6 multiple db hits with linq expressions passed as parameters

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I have a query (users filtered by some parameters) , which I am interested to left outer join with another query (aggregations on users which made purchases) and fill zeros for users which do not exist in the second query result.

I use static expression trees, wich get executed dynamically when the whole query is matrialized, like:

```
public static Func<ApplicationUser, bool> IsPassedDisclaimerLambda
    {
        get { return u => u.Roles.Any(ro => ro.Role.Name 
            == SystemConstants.Roles.MobileUser_PassedDisclaimer); }
    }
```

When I write the lambda expression inline, like

```
var users = Db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(ro => ro.Role.Name 
    == SystemConstants.Roles.MobileUser_PassedDisclaimer));
```

in the time of materialization, the query gets executed as a single DB hit.

and when I use

```
var users = Db.Users.Where(ApplicationUser.IsPassedDisclaimerLambda);
```

the query works (after I put `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in the connection string), but I see in the log a DB hit for each user and not simple left outer join, which I would expect.

It's like EF materialized the first query, and then goes to the DB for each user to create the grouping.

Why can it be and what can be done?

The code:

```
public ActionResult UsersSummary(ReportFilter filter)
{

    var purchases = FilterPurchases(filter);

    //users which made purchases - works "fine" - creates a 210-line query, execution time 410 ms for some 50k rows
    var rows = purchases.Where(pu => pu.Valid).GroupBy(p => p.Buyer.UserName).Select(gr =>
        new UserSummary
        {
            Name = gr.Key,
            PurchasesCount = gr.Count(),
            PurchasesSum = gr.AsQueryable().Sum(Purchase.CurrentPurchaseSumLambda) ?? 0,
            ReturnSumPending = gr.AsQueryable().Sum(Purchase.CurrentUnpaidSumLambda) ?? 0,
            ReturnSumReceived = gr.AsQueryable().Sum(Purchase.CurrentPaidSumLambda) ?? 0,
            TotalReturnSum = gr.AsQueryable().Sum(Purchase.TotalReturnSumLambda) ?? 0
        });


    //var users = Db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(ro => ro.Role.Name == SystemConstants.Roles.MobileUser_PassedDisclaimer));  //1 hit
    var users = Db.Users.Where(ApplicationUser.IsPassedDisclaimerLambda);  //multiple hits


    //left outer join
    var total = users.GroupJoin(rows, u => u.UserName, r => r.Name, (u, g) => g
        .Select(r => new UserSummary
        {
            Name = u.UserName,
            PurchasesCount = r.PurchasesCount,
            PurchasesSum = r.PurchasesSum,
            ReturnSumPending = r.ReturnSumPending,
            ReturnSumReceived = r.ReturnSumReceived,
            TotalReturnSum = r.TotalReturnSum
        })
        .DefaultIfEmpty(new UserSummary
        {
            Name = u.UserName,
            PurchasesCount = 0,
            PurchasesSum = 0,
            ReturnSumPending = 0,
            ReturnSumReceived = 0,
            TotalReturnSum = 0
        }))
        .SelectMany(gr => gr);

    var ret = total.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList();

    return View(ret);

}
```

with

```
var users = Db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(ro => ro.Role.Name == SystemConstants.Roles.MobileUser_PassedDisclaimer));
```

I get 1 big query which is executed in 500 ms

```
Opened connection at 28/04/2014 11:17:11 +03:00
SELECT 
    [Project20].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project20].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project20].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project20].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [Project20].[C5] AS [C5], 
    [Project20].[C6] AS [C6], 
    [Project20].[C7] AS [C7]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        CASE WHEN ([Project18].[C10] IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE [Project18].[C10] END AS [C1], 
        CASE WHEN ([Project18].[C10] IS NULL) THEN [Extent1].[UserName] WHEN ([Project18].[C10] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE [Extent1].[UserName] END AS [C2], 
        CASE WHEN ([Project18].[C10] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Project18].[C1] END AS [C3], 
        CASE WHEN ([Project18].[C10] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float(53)) WHEN ([Project18].[C10] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS float) WHEN ([Project18].[C2] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float(53)) ELSE [Project18].[C3] END AS [C4], 
        CASE WHEN ([Project18].[C10] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float(53)) WHEN ([Project18].[C10] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS float) WHEN ([Project18].[C4] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float(53)) ELSE [Project18].[C5] END AS [C5], 
        CASE WHEN ([Project18].[C10] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float(53)) WHEN ([Project18].[C10] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS float) WHEN ([Project18].[C6] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float(53)) ELSE [Project18].[C7] END AS [C6], 
        CASE WHEN ([Project18].[C10] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float(53)) WHEN ([Project18].[C10] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS float) WHEN ([Project18].[C8] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float(53)) ELSE [Project18].[C9] END AS [C7]
        FROM  [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
            [Project17].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
            [Project17].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project17].[C2] AS [C2], 
            [Project17].[C3] AS [C3], 
            [Project17].[C4] AS [C4], 
            [Project17].[C5] AS [C5], 
            [Project17].[C6] AS [C6], 
            [Project17].[C7] AS [C7], 
            [Project17].[C8] AS [C8], 
            [Project17].[C9] AS [C9], 
            1 AS [C10]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project16].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                [Project16].[C1] AS [C1], 
                [Project16].[C2] AS [C2], 
                [Project16].[C3] AS [C3], 
                [Project16].[C4] AS [C4], 
                [Project16].[C5] AS [C5], 
                [Project16].[C6] AS [C6], 
                [Project16].[C7] AS [C7], 
                [Project16].[C8] AS [C8], 
                (SELECT 
                    SUM([Filter22].[A1]) AS [A1]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        (SELECT 
                            SUM([Extent33].[Sum]) AS [A1]
                            FROM [dbo].[UserPayments] AS [Extent33]
                            WHERE ([Extent31].[ID] = [Extent33].[Purchase_ID]) OR (([Extent31].[ID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent33].[Purchase_ID] IS NULL))) AS [A1]
                        FROM  [dbo].[Purchases] AS [Extent31]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent32] ON ([Extent32].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser') AND ([Extent31].[Buyer_Id] = [Extent32].[Id])
                        WHERE ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__0, [Extent31].[PurchaseTime])) >= 0) AND ([Extent31].[Valid] = 1) AND (([Project16].[UserName] = [Extent32].[UserName]) OR (([Project16].[UserName] IS NULL) AND ([Extent32].[UserName] IS NULL)))
                    )  AS [Filter22]) AS [C9]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project15].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                    [Project15].[C1] AS [C1], 
                    [Project15].[C2] AS [C2], 
                    [Project15].[C3] AS [C3], 
                    [Project15].[C4] AS [C4], 
                    [Project15].[C5] AS [C5], 
                    [Project15].[C6] AS [C6], 
                    [Project15].[C7] AS [C7], 
                    (SELECT 
                        SUM([Filter20].[A1]) AS [A1]
                        FROM ( SELECT 
                            (SELECT 
                                SUM([Extent30].[Sum]) AS [A1]
                                FROM [dbo].[UserPayments] AS [Extent30]
                                WHERE ([Extent28].[ID] = [Extent30].[Purchase_ID]) OR (([Extent28].[ID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent30].[Purchase_ID] IS NULL))) AS [A1]
                            FROM  [dbo].[Purchases] AS [Extent28]
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent29] ON ([Extent29].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser') AND ([Extent28].[Buyer_Id] = [Extent29].[Id])
                            WHERE ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__0, [Extent28].[PurchaseTime])) >= 0) AND ([Extent28].[Valid] = 1) AND (([Project15].[UserName] = [Extent29].[UserName]) OR (([Project15].[UserName] IS NULL) AND ([Extent29].[UserName] IS NULL)))
                        )  AS [Filter20]) AS [C8]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Project14].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                        [Project14].[C1] AS [C1], 
                        [Project14].[C2] AS [C2], 
                        [Project14].[C3] AS [C3], 
                        [Project14].[C4] AS [C4], 
                        [Project14].[C5] AS [C5], 
                        [Project14].[C6] AS [C6], 
                        (SELECT 
                            SUM([Filter18].[A1]) AS [A1]
                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                (SELECT 
                                    SUM([Extent27].[Sum]) AS [A1]
                                    FROM [dbo].[UserPayments] AS [Extent27]
                                    WHERE (([Extent25].[ID] = [Extent27].[Purchase_ID]) OR (([Extent25].[ID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent27].[Purchase_ID] IS NULL))) AND (N'Paid' = [Extent27].[Status])) AS [A1]
                                FROM  [dbo].[Purchases] AS [Extent25]
                                INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent26] ON ([Extent26].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser') AND ([Extent25].[Buyer_Id] = [Extent26].[Id])
                                WHERE ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__0, [Extent25].[PurchaseTime])) >= 0) AND ([Extent25].[Valid] = 1) AND (([Project14].[UserName] = [Extent26].[UserName]) OR (([Project14].[UserName] IS NULL) AND ([Extent26].[UserName] IS NULL)))
                            )  AS [Filter18]) AS [C7]
                        FROM ( SELECT 
                            [Project13].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                            [Project13].[C1] AS [C1], 
                            [Project13].[C2] AS [C2], 
                            [Project13].[C3] AS [C3], 
                            [Project13].[C4] AS [C4], 
                            [Project13].[C5] AS [C5], 
                            (SELECT 
                                SUM([Filter16].[A1]) AS [A1]
                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                    (SELECT 
                                        SUM([Extent24].[Sum]) AS [A1]
                                        FROM [dbo].[UserPayments] AS [Extent24]
                                        WHERE (([Extent22].[ID] = [Extent24].[Purchase_ID]) OR (([Extent22].[ID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent24].[Purchase_ID] IS NULL))) AND (N'Paid' = [Extent24].[Status])) AS [A1]
                                    FROM  [dbo].[Purchases] AS [Extent22]
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent23] ON ([Extent23].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser') AND ([Extent22].[Buyer_Id] = [Extent23].[Id])
                                    WHERE ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__0, [Extent22].[PurchaseTime])) >= 0) AND ([Extent22].[Valid] = 1) AND (([Project13].[UserName] = [Extent23].[UserName]) OR (([Project13].[UserName] IS NULL) AND ([Extent23].[UserName] IS NULL)))
                                )  AS [Filter16]) AS [C6]
                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                [Project12].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                                [Project12].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                [Project12].[C2] AS [C2], 
                                [Project12].[C3] AS [C3], 
                                [Project12].[C4] AS [C4], 
                                (SELECT 
                                    SUM([Filter14].[A1]) AS [A1]
                                    FROM ( SELECT 
                                        (SELECT 
                                            SUM([Extent21].[Sum]) AS [A1]
                                            FROM [dbo].[UserPayments] AS [Extent21]
                                            WHERE (([Extent19].[ID] = [Extent21].[Purchase_ID]) OR (([Extent19].[ID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent21].[Purchase_ID] IS NULL))) AND ( NOT ((N'Paid' = [Extent21].[Status]) AND ([Extent21].[Status] IS NOT NULL)))) AS [A1]
                                        FROM  [dbo].[Purchases] AS [Extent19]
                                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent20] ON ([Extent20].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser') AND ([Extent19].[Buyer_Id] = [Extent20].[Id])
                                        WHERE ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__0, [Extent19].[PurchaseTime])) >= 0) AND ([Extent19].[Valid] = 1) AND (([Project12].[UserName] = [Extent20].[UserName]) OR (([Project12].[UserName] IS NULL) AND ([Extent20].[UserName] IS NULL)))
                                    )  AS [Filter14]) AS [C5]
                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                    [Project11].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                                    [Project11].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                    [Project11].[C2] AS [C2], 
                                    [Project11].[C3] AS [C3], 
                                    (SELECT 
                                        SUM([Filter12].[A1]) AS [A1]
                                        FROM ( SELECT 
                                            (SELECT 
                                                SUM([Extent18].[Sum]) AS [A1]
                                                FROM [dbo].[UserPayments] AS [Extent18]
                                                WHERE (([Extent16].[ID] = [Extent18].[Purchase_ID]) OR (([Extent16].[ID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent18].[Purchase_ID] IS NULL))) AND ( NOT ((N'Paid' = [Extent18].[Status]) AND ([Extent18].[Status] IS NOT NULL)))) AS [A1]
                                            FROM  [dbo].[Purchases] AS [Extent16]
                                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent17] ON ([Extent17].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser') AND ([Extent16].[Buyer_Id] = [Extent17].[Id])
                                            WHERE ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__0, [Extent16].[PurchaseTime])) >= 0) AND ([Extent16].[Valid] = 1) AND (([Project11].[UserName] = [Extent17].[UserName]) OR (([Project11].[UserName] IS NULL) AND ([Extent17].[UserName] IS NULL)))
                                        )  AS [Filter12]) AS [C4]
                                    FROM ( SELECT 
                                        [Project6].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                                        [Project6].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                        [Project6].[C2] AS [C2], 
                                        (SELECT 
                                            SUM([Apply4].[A1]) AS [A1]
                                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                                CASE WHEN ([Project9].[EntrySum] IS NULL) THEN CASE WHEN (cast(0 as float(53)) - ((SELECT 
                                                    SUM([Extent15].[EntrySum]) AS [A1]
                                                    FROM [dbo].[PurchaseHistories] AS [Extent15]
                                                    WHERE (([Project9].[ID] = [Extent15].[Purchase_ID]) OR (([Project9].[ID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent15].[Purchase_ID] IS NULL))) AND (N'PartialReturn' = [Extent15].[EntryType]))) IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float(53)) ELSE cast(0 as float(53)) - ((SELECT 
                                                    SUM([Extent14].[EntrySum]) AS [A1]
                                                    FROM [dbo].[PurchaseHistories] AS [Extent14]
                                                    WHERE (([Project9].[ID] = [Extent14].[Purchase_ID]) OR (([Project9].[ID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent14].[Purchase_ID] IS NULL))) AND (N'PartialReturn' = [Extent14].[EntryType]))) END ELSE [Element4].[EntrySum] END AS [A1]
                                                FROM   (SELECT 
                                                    [Project7].[ID] AS [ID], 
                                                    [Element3].[EntrySum] AS [EntrySum]
                                                    FROM   (SELECT 
                                                        [Extent10].[ID] AS [ID]
                                                        FROM  [dbo].[Purchases] AS [Extent10]
                                                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent11] ON ([Extent11].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser') AND ([Extent10].[Buyer_Id] = [Extent11].[Id])
                                                        WHERE ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__0, [Extent10].[PurchaseTime])) >= 0) AND ([Extent10].[Valid] = 1) AND (([Project6].[UserName] = [Extent11].[UserName]) OR (([Project6].[UserName] IS NULL) AND ([Extent11].[UserName] IS NULL))) ) AS [Project7]
                                                    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
                                                        [Extent12].[EntryType] AS [EntryType], 
                                                        [Extent12].[EntrySum] AS [EntrySum], 
                                                        [Extent12].[Purchase_ID] AS [Purchase_ID]
                                                        FROM [dbo].[PurchaseHistories] AS [Extent12]
                                                        WHERE ([Project7].[ID] = [Extent12].[Purchase_ID]) AND (N'NewPurchase' = [Extent12].[EntryType]) ) AS [Element3] ) AS [Project9]
                                                OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
                                                    [Extent13].[EntryType] AS [EntryType], 
                                                    [Extent13].[EntrySum] AS [EntrySum], 
                                                    [Extent13].[Purchase_ID] AS [Purchase_ID]
                                                    FROM [dbo].[PurchaseHistories] AS [Extent13]
                                                    WHERE ([Project9].[ID] = [Extent13].[Purchase_ID]) AND (N'NewPurchase' = [Extent13].[EntryType]) ) AS [Element4]
                                            )  AS [Apply4]) AS [C3]
                                        FROM ( SELECT 
                                            [Project1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                                            [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                            (SELECT 
                                                SUM([Apply2].[A1]) AS [A1]
                                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                                    CASE WHEN ([Project4].[EntrySum] IS NULL) THEN CASE WHEN (cast(0 as float(53)) - ((SELECT 
                                                        SUM([Extent9].[EntrySum]) AS [A1]
                                                        FROM [dbo].[PurchaseHistories] AS [Extent9]
                                                        WHERE (([Project4].[ID] = [Extent9].[Purchase_ID]) OR (([Project4].[ID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent9].[Purchase_ID] IS NULL))) AND (N'PartialReturn' = [Extent9].[EntryType]))) IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as float(53)) ELSE cast(0 as float(53)) - ((SELECT 
                                                        SUM([Extent8].[EntrySum]) AS [A1]
                                                        FROM [dbo].[PurchaseHistories] AS [Extent8]
                                                        WHERE (([Project4].[ID] = [Extent8].[Purchase_ID]) OR (([Project4].[ID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent8].[Purchase_ID] IS NULL))) AND (N'PartialReturn' = [Extent8].[EntryType]))) END ELSE [Element2].[EntrySum] END AS [A1]
                                                    FROM   (SELECT 
                                                        [Project2].[ID] AS [ID], 
                                                        [Element1].[EntrySum] AS [EntrySum]
                                                        FROM   (SELECT 
                                                            [Extent4].[ID] AS [ID]
                                                            FROM  [dbo].[Purchases] AS [Extent4]
                                                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent5] ON ([Extent5].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser') AND ([Extent4].[Buyer_Id] = [Extent5].[Id])
                                                            WHERE ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__0, [Extent4].[PurchaseTime])) >= 0) AND ([Extent4].[Valid] = 1) AND (([Project1].[UserName] = [Extent5].[UserName]) OR (([Project1].[UserName] IS NULL) AND ([Extent5].[UserName] IS NULL))) ) AS [Project2]
                                                        OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
                                                            [Extent6].[EntryType] AS [EntryType], 
                                                            [Extent6].[EntrySum] AS [EntrySum], 
                                                            [Extent6].[Purchase_ID] AS [Purchase_ID]
                                                            FROM [dbo].[PurchaseHistories] AS [Extent6]
                                                            WHERE ([Project2].[ID] = [Extent6].[Purchase_ID]) AND (N'NewPurchase' = [Extent6].[EntryType]) ) AS [Element1] ) AS [Project4]
                                                    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
                                                        [Extent7].[EntryType] AS [EntryType], 
                                                        [Extent7].[EntrySum] AS [EntrySum], 
                                                        [Extent7].[Purchase_ID] AS [Purchase_ID]
                                                        FROM [dbo].[PurchaseHistories] AS [Extent7]
                                                        WHERE ([Project4].[ID] = [Extent7].[Purchase_ID]) AND (N'NewPurchase' = [Extent7].[EntryType]) ) AS [Element2]
                                                )  AS [Apply2]) AS [C2]
                                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                                [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [UserName], 
                                                [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
                                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                                    [Extent3].[UserName] AS [K1], 
                                                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                                                    FROM  [dbo].[Purchases] AS [Extent2]
                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent3].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser') AND ([Extent2].[Buyer_Id] = [Extent3].[Id])
                                                    WHERE ((DATEDIFF (minute, @p__linq__0, [Extent2].[PurchaseTime])) >= 0) AND ([Extent2].[Valid] = 1)
                                                    GROUP BY [Extent3].[UserName]
                                                )  AS [GroupBy1]
                                            )  AS [Project1]
                                        )  AS [Project6]
                                    )  AS [Project11]
                                )  AS [Project12]
                            )  AS [Project13]
                        )  AS [Project14]
                    )  AS [Project15]
                )  AS [Project16]
            )  AS [Project17] ) AS [Project18] ON ([Extent1].[UserName] = [Project18].[UserName]) OR (([Extent1].[UserName] IS NULL) AND ([Project18].[UserName] IS NULL))
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser') AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM  [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] AS [Extent34]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetRoles] AS [Extent35] ON [Extent34].[RoleId] = [Extent35].[Id]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent34].[UserId]) AND (N'PassedDisclaimer' = [Extent35].[Name])
        ))
    )  AS [Project20]
    ORDER BY [Project20].[C2] ASC
```

with

```
var users = Db.Users.Where(ApplicationUser.IsPassedDisclaimerLambda);
```

I get selection of the first query, and then separate DB hit to Roles table for each user like that:

```
    SELECT 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: 'f6a7a631-a237-40e7-9efc-92747cd2305f' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 128)
-- Executing at 28/04/2014 11:23:07 +03:00
-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: 'fe12b621-2f07-41d1-8e24-7b80315b2c8e' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 128)
-- Executing at 28/04/2014 11:23:07 +03:00
-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader

...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
public static Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, bool>> IsPassedDisclaimerLambda
{
    get { return u => u.Roles.Any(ro => ro.Role.Name 
        == SystemConstants.Roles.MobileUser_PassedDisclaimer); }
}
```

rather than

```
public static Func<ApplicationUser, bool> IsPassedDisclaimerLambda
{
    get { return u => u.Roles.Any(ro => ro.Role.Name 
        == SystemConstants.Roles.MobileUser_PassedDisclaimer); }
}
```

Passing expression rather than delegate will allow EF to build a query out of the expression. On the other hand, if you pass a delegate, there is no way to apply it other than "per-row".